# in iOS7 the [alert show] cause app crash

Tags: crash, ios7, uialertview, alert

My codes in iOS6, iOS5 works fine, but after i installed xcode5, and run my app in iOS7. the app is crashed in line of [alert show] . and the error info is:**Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3)**

I don't know why. anybody can help me. Thank you!

my codes:

```
- (void) whetherRememberDialog{

dialogFlag = WHETHER_REMEMBER_DIALOG;

    NSString *titleInfo = @"Whether remember?";
    NSString *cancelInfo = @"cancel";
    NSString *okInfo = @"Ok";

    UIAlertView *storeQuesitonDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:titleInfo
                                                                  message:nil
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:cancelInfo
                                                        otherButtonTitles:okInfo, nil];
    //[storeQuesitonDialog show];
    [storeQuesitonDialog performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; // In this line the app is crash this codes 
    [storeQuesitonDialog release];
```

}

Crash log:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xa6608, 0x3ac2fb62 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 2, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3)
frame #0: 0x3ac2fb62 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 2
frame #1: 0x330d2ab0 UIKit`-[UIImageView _shouldTreatImageAsTemplate:] + 24
frame #2: 0x330d2a78 UIKit`-[UIImageView _effectiveTintColorWithImage:] + 24
frame #3: 0x330d3980 UIKit`-[UIImageView tintColorDidChange] + 80
frame #4: 0x330ccc2a UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _recursiveNotifyInteractionTintColorDidChangeForReasons:] + 98
frame #5: 0x330ccce8 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _recursiveNotifyInteractionTintColorDidChangeForReasons:] + 288
frame #6: 0x330ccce8 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _recursiveNotifyInteractionTintColorDidChangeForReasons:] + 288
frame #7: 0x330ccce8 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _recursiveNotifyInteractionTintColorDidChangeForReasons:] + 288
frame #8: 0x330ccce8 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _recursiveNotifyInteractionTintColorDidChangeForReasons:] + 288
frame #9: 0x330ccce8 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _recursiveNotifyInteractionTintColorDidChangeForReasons:] + 288
frame #10: 0x330ccce8 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _recursiveNotifyInteractionTintColorDidChangeForReasons:] + 288
frame #11: 0x330ccce8 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _recursiveNotifyInteractionTintColorDidChangeForReasons:] + 288
frame #12: 0x330ccce8 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _recursiveNotifyInteractionTintColorDidChangeForReasons:] + 288
frame #13: 0x330ccce8 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _recursiveNotifyInteractionTintColorDidChangeForReasons:] + 288
frame #14: 0x332d60ea UIKit`-[_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController _desaturateUI] + 210
frame #15: 0x332d18f0 UIKit`-[_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController _dismissItem:andPresentItem:animated:completion:keepDimmingView:] + 416
frame #16: 0x332d174a UIKit`-[_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController _dismissItem:andPresentItem:animated:completion:] + 38
frame #17: 0x332d0f6e UIKit`-[_UIModalItemsCoordinator _presentItem:replacingItem:inViewController:animated:] + 1198
frame #18: 0x332d0aa8 UIKit`-[UIViewController(UIModalItemPresentationSupport) presentModalItem:replacing:animated:dontPresentAndAddToStack:] + 120
frame #19: 0x332d0a2c UIKit`-[UIViewController(UIModalItemPresentationSupport) presentModalItem:animated:] + 32
frame #20: 0x332cf77c UIKit`-[UIAlertView(Private) popupAlertAnimated:animationType:atOffset:] + 968
frame #21: 0x332cf3ae UIKit`-[UIAlertView(Private) popupAlertAnimated:animationType:] + 34
frame #22: 0x3126f19c Foundation`-[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 744
frame #23: 0x31272b54 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 136
frame #24: 0x000dd7f0 PPExam`-[ExamPageViewController whetherRememberDialog](self=0x16e9c930, _cmd=0x001fa7ec) + 316 at ExamPageViewController.m:1043
frame #25: 0x000dbbb8 PPExam`-[ExamPageViewController backToChapterNaviController:](self=0x16e9c930, _cmd=0x001fa802, sender=0x16ea5870) + 68 at ExamPageViewController.m:743
frame #26: 0x330f555e UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
frame #27: 0x330f54fa UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 38
frame #28: 0x330f54ca UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 46
frame #29: 0x330e10f2 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
frame #30: 0x330f4f12 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 594
frame #31: 0x330f4bdc UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 528
frame #32: 0x330efc08 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 832
frame #33: 0x330c4f58 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
frame #34: 0x330c3746 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7114
frame #35: 0x30905f26 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
frame #36: 0x309053ee CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
frame #37: 0x30903bde CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 630
frame #38: 0x3086e540 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
frame #39: 0x3086e322 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
frame #40: 0x355a52ea GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 138
frame #41: 0x331251e4 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
frame #42: 0x000b6ce0 PPExam`main(argc=1, argv=0x27d51c7c) + 100 at main.m:14
```

Comment: The crash looks unrelated to the alert view, except insofar as showing it is changing the tint color of your views. It appears that you have an image view which is in a bad state - perhaps its image was over-deallocated? Try running your code with NSZombieEnabled turned on and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you Jesse, Base on instruments, i found the solution.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. You should post an answer explaining how you fixed the issue and accept it so that people finding this in the future can see what the problem was.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot manually release objects in iOS 7 because of ARC. ARC manages object deallocation for you, so you should not release the object. This could cause ARC to release the object after you already did, causing it to throw an error. Also, if you release the alert view, how is it supposed to show on the screen? Removing the release may fix this for you.

Comment: [storeQuesitonDialog performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; // In this line the app is crash. so the alert hasn't released.

Comment: ARC has nothing to do with OS version.
You have to release the alertview because `show` will increase the retainCount.
The correct way is to perform the whole method on the mainThread, not only `show`